# Is it possible to run Ubuntu in a virtual machine and be able to boot to it?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware, multi-boot

Say I were to install Ubuntu Linux onto a virtual machine (or the other way around, installing it to dual boot), and keep it's files on it's own partition. Is there a way the computer could also boot straight to the Ubuntu installation, allowing for me to either use it as a VM while running on Windows, or dual boot it when I want more power?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, technically this is possible, using **raw mappings**.

You would basically install Linux normally, as a second OS, so you will be able to dual boot. Then in Workstation, for example, you would use the existing OS install as the drive for the VM.

Have a look at this article on the VMware website: [Configuring a Dual-Boot Computer for Use with a Virtual Machine](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_disk_dualboot.html) for a guide on how to do this.